# Provide a Ticket Number in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script

Okay, here's what I'm doing. I want to create a form where users can request assistance. The form fills up 10 columns of a table. The 11th column is a ticket number generated by a formula along the lines of `=int(date)&"-"&row(a1)` - A unique value for each row with info. Anyway...

After the user presses submit when submitting the form, is there **any way** to use a script to show them the unique number generated? Or is this putting the cart before the horse?

Thanks for any assist!

Comment: Consider instead Microsoft Forms see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-a-form-template-by-using-a-script-a537013f-1935-44dc-9211-d8438f7f207c

Answer (score 1):

You can use a form submission trigger function to generate an email to the user with the results of their form, including the ticket number column. There are [plenty of examples of such scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20form%20submission%20email%20is:question).

There is no way to generate a custom confirmation message on the fly; [Forms.setConfirmationMessage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setConfirmationMessage%28String%29) is able to set the message, but you have no way to trigger that in the middle of form submission.

If you must provide the feedback about a ticket number as part of the form work-flow, then you must depart the Forms service and create a custom form using the UiService or HtmlService.

Comment: As a side note, even HtmlService cannot let one to create that for every user you have to create a new form??